# What things can the other person see about my phone when I pair it using bluetooth?

Tags: mobile, phone, bluetooth

I need to know some correct information about bluetooth pairing technology. What are the things which becomes visible to the person about my phone when I'm using bluetooth from my phone and pairing it with another phone? 
I mean what information does the other person get to see in their phone when I'm pairing my phone with them?

I know a little about it, for instance that my music, images and documents files appears on the other person's phone.
But what other information becomes visible to them? Does my contacts, messages (texts) also appears in their phone?

Comment: I am pretty sure the paired phone can see anything you gave it permission to see when pairing is set up...

Comment: It would be helpful if you could tell us exactly how you paired the two devices. There are many bluetooth profiles that differ in what they share. Also, many of the pairing options have additional security options that go with them. The more information you can give us, the more we can help.

Comment: @Bubble Hacker what do you mean by 'anything' ? And it just asks for permission once only. It doesnot ask for permission individually. Im sorry, if im talking stupid. But please help.

Comment: @user113653 When pairing the two devices the device asking to pair asks for permission for specific services and all services that were not accepted will not work.

Comment: It depends on which profiles both phones agreed to talk with. Some share pictures, contacts, texts, etc.

Answer (score 3):

All information that is available through your phones supported profiles. For modern smart phones this will most likely include:

- SIM and device contacts
- SMS messages
- Your phone uinique bluetooth MAC

If your phone supports advanced bluetooth profiles such as OBEX (all Android phones that I owned so far did not support this out of the box)

- Read/Write/Delete files inside of a defined root directory

Many more bluetooth profiles may be implemented on your device, a defintive answer will be totally specific to your model.